# regex to match several string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have questions with regex in Python.

Possible variations can be

10 hours, 12 weeks or 7 business days.

I want to have my regex something like

```
string = "I have an 7 business day trip and 12 weeks vacation."
re.findall(r'\d+\s(business)?\s(hours|weeks|days)', string)
```

so that I expect to find "7 business day" and "12 weeks" but it returns None

Comment: thanks, I have correct that. but now it returns [("business", "day"), ("weeks")] without number.

Comment: Now if there's no `business` you require *two* whitespace characters.

Comment: you forgot to match characters between "business" & "12".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string = "I have an 7 business day trip and 12 weeks vacation."
print re.findall(r'\d+\s(?:business\s)?(?:hour|week|day)s?', string)
['7 business day', '12 weeks']

\d+\s(?:business\s)?(?:hour|week|day)s?
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Ytu1HFfbmsd3BpFV)

The demo should explain how this works. The reason yours wasn't is because it was looking for `7 businessdays` which doesn't match.

Although if you don't want to accept `business week/hour`, you'll need to modify it further:

```
\d+\s(?:hour|week|(?:business )?day)s?
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/DeXvPszNWq8p7qVq)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tweak your regex to this:

```
>>> string = "I have an 7 business day trip and 12 weeks vacation."
>>> print re.findall(r'(\d+)\s*(?:business day|hour|week)s?', string)
['7', '12']
```

This matches any number that is followed by `business day` or `hour` or `week` and an optional `s` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @anubhava's answer but matches "7 business day" rather than just "7". Just move the closing parenthesis from after \d+ to the end:

```
re.findall(r'(\d+\s*(?:business day|hour|week)s?)', string)
```

Comment: If you don't include any capture groups, then `re.findall` will return the entire match by default, so the parentheses are not necessary.

Answer (score -2):

\d+\s+(business\s)?(hour|week|day)s?

Comment: code only answers are generally not as helpful as an explanation of how or why. Also, there is a formatter for code (the `{}` button)

Comment: this is not a code fragment, but rather a regex string to use to get desired output. I could have written "You need to tweak your regex to this:" but I thought it is rather implied.

Comment: which still doesn't explain **why** this is the right answer, or **how** the regex works (or, alternatively, why their regex doesn't). Those are important. Notice the accepted answer gives a solution, the reason why his approach doesn't work and a demo to test against. Normally I also do a breakdown, but Debuggex does an excellent job of doing a visual breakdown if you click through the link.